# How do I create a new JSON object with PL/JSON?

Tags: json, plsql, pljson

Let's say I want to create the following JSON structure in PL/JSON:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": 42,
  "foobar": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is to simply pass the string to the JSON type constructor like so:

```
declare
  json_obj json;
begin
  json_obj := json('{"foo":"bar", "baz":42, "foobar": [1,2,3]}');
end;
/
```

But let's pretend you are building this JSON object from data in your database. Then you would do something like the following:

```
declare
  json_obj json := json();
  json_ar  json_list := json_list();
begin
  -- Add the string elements
  json_obj.put('foo', 'bar');
  json_obj.put('baz', 42);

  -- Add elements to the array ("list" in PL/JSON)
  json_ar.append(1);
  json_ar.append(2);
  json_ar.append(3);
  -- Add the array to the object
  json_obj.put('foobar', json_ar);

  -- Print it just for fun
  json_obj.pretty_print
end;
/
```

Comment: Can we convert this json object to varchar2?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the subject of this question.

Comment: Yes, but could you give me a tip?

Comment: It's in the documentation -- http://pljson.github.io/pljson/ . There's even a great big diagram showing all the methods you would need.